# "Find Usages" in 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij with Maven, so it's very easy to download the source code of any 3rd party library I'm using (assuming it posted the source to the Maven repository, of course). Is it possible to find usages of a method within that 3rd party library?

In other words, I would like to use IntelliJ's "Find Usages" action and find usages that aren't in my code, but in the 3rd party source code. Is it possible? If not in IntelliJ, is there another tool that does this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I have found out that you can search for usages. When you ALT-F7 (find usages) on a method, simply select your scope as being **Project and Libraries** instead of just Project or Module. This works perfectly for me. Finds all usages of methods etc. in other libraries that have source code included.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
I don't **think** that is possible (I might be wrong, so if anyone knows I would also be interested in the answer). As I understand it, adding the source code simply gives you the ability to "see" what is going on in that code. It is not *really* included in you project. IntelliJ only indexes your own project for finding usages etc.

As for other applications, I do not know :)

Comment: Intellij does index 3rd party code. When you "Go to class", you can find 3rd party code through it.

Comment: That is true. Maybe in a similar fashion you can force IntelliJ to find usages in 3rd party code. I will have a go and see if I can find anything.

Comment: Great, this will be most useful. I was doing CTRL-ALT-F7, which simply does nothing on external methods.

Comment: I had to press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F7 together to show "Find Usages" dialog.

Comment: For a Mac I had to press Shift-Alt-Cmd-F7 together. As if life wasn't complicated enough already

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ's Find Usages feature has scope "Project" and "Project and Libraries" (which includes your maven dependencies). It seems to me the "Project and Libraries" is not available on symbols defined in your source code, but is available on symbols defined in your dependencies.